# Is there a way to get LaTeX to place figures and tables in the order they are referenced in the text?

Tags: latex

I think this question is novel. Here is the problem I have. I have a relatively short piece of text associated with a lot of figures and a table. I want floats to appear on pages just for floats but in the order I specify. I have set all of the table and figure parameters to [hp] and placed them in the order I want them to appear in the source e.g.

Figure 1

Figure 2

Figure 3

Table 1

Figure 4

Figure 5

The problem I have is that no matter what I do the document typesets like this

Table 1

Figure 1

Figure 2

etc....

I have tried trashing the Aux files before typesetting. I am aware of the endfloats package but I still want latex to place the floats in between larger sections of txts in other parts of the document. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/547614/19501

Comment: This belongs on http://tex.stackexchange.com nowadays.

Answer (score 9):

I'll try to explain why the fix by @user476160 (placement modifier `hp` instead of just `p`) works. A `figure` is a *float*, i.e. an element that cannot be broken across a page.  The `figure` environment accepts a parameter list with placement hints:

```
\begin{figure}[placement parameters]
% ...
\end{figure}
```

The placement specifier `h` stands for *here* and places the figure *approximately* at the same point as in the source text. The placement specifier `p` puts the `figure` in a special page that contains only floats:

```
\begin{figure}[hp]
% ...
\end{figure}
```

[Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions) has an excellent article on figure placement if you want to fine-tune your figure and table placement.

I also recommend posting LaTeX-related questions in the [TeX Stack Exchange Q&A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved, the first figure in my list had the parameter [p] rather [hp]. This seemed to cause latex a lot of grief for some reason. Anyhow problem solved for now. The figures and txt all appear in the order I have specified.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easy. All you have to do is use this package.

```
\usepackage{float}
```

And you have to change the figure parameters to

```
\begin{figure}{H}
%..
\end{figure]}
```

Let me know if it works :)